# Way to convert PBR "glossy specular" > "specular" (color value) for cycles nodes group?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, pbr

We can use principled bsdf as PBR metalness roughness workflow shader.And there are arleady some good tutorialls how to make PBR shader (aproximately) from cycles nodes, for "metalness roughness" workflow, thanks.

But I hope to know way to convert "PBR specular glossiness" shader for cycles
(for electric or dielectric).

Is there good example of cycles shader nodes group, which may mimic "Specular glossiness" PBR shader?  it may offer way to convert "specular" color value correctly?

Blender principled bsdf "specular" is mono value, and it seems same as "reflectivity" which is circulated by "ior" value.

Most of case we may use ior 1.5 then it may convert as reflectivity 0.5,
(principled bsdf specular) or to get more precise effect, we may use formula.

Then I can convert "reflectivity" value to ior value when I convert material
to use cycles fresnel node.

But I hope to know, is there good way to convert  "specular" color value which used for "PBR specular glossiness" workflow as cycles PBR shader?

I feel, specular color(for PBR specular glossiness shader) value is already include "Ior", is it right? or it  use "ior" set as one value (1.5 etc) to cicrulate fresnell?) Anyway I do not know, correct way to mimic "specular" color value, as cycles shader nodes. which can use for directric and metal.

I really apreciate, if someone already made PBR "Specular glossiness" workflow shader for cycles. Is there good tutorial or document which make it?